# Custom filters - how do I make them fail?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm creating a package that allows users to use a custom filter.

So far I have a method called:

```
public function testFilter(){


    return false;

}
```

In my filters file, in my main app I have I have:

```
Route::filter('test.test', MyPackage::testFilter());
```

And in my routes, in my main app I have:

```
'before'=>'test.test'
```

My question is, how do I do the filtering, I've done a return false to try and make the filter fail, do I need something else, like app abort?

Answer (score 1):

According to Laravel filters documentation

> If the filter returns a response, that response is considered the response to the request and the route will not execute. Any after filters on the route are also cancelled.

That means you do have to return a `Response` to cancel your route from proceeding.

It'll probably more logical for you have another view to be displayed to your visitor when the filter fails, and this is what Laravel is trying to do.

You can use `App::abort()` for that or `App::abort(404)` (with error codes) to show error page.